# How to handle Site-minder redirection for user authentication while API testing using RestAssured Java?

Tags: single-sign-on, rest-assured, siteminder

Scenario: I am sending GET request to a microservice to get JSON responses. But in my project, we have siteminder which handles SSO authentications. So whats happening here is after sending a fresh request (no session cookies) to microservice it's getting redirected to the siteminder for user authentication. When I am using a web browser I get the option to put my user credentials. But when I am using Rest-assured using Java to do so it is failing to handle site minder and sending me back 401 error.

How can I handle this scenario?

I have already tried these,
 RestAssured.authentication = basic("un","pw")
 RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()

Answer (score 0):

CA SSO (aka SiteMinder) does this little annoying extra step to prevent pre-emptive basic authentication requests. Add a cookie to your request SMCHALLENGE=YES should get you through.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share a sample code?

Comment: I just tried this. Didn't get through. My code: 

`@Test 
public void testStatusCodeRestAssured () 
{ 
RestAssured.authentication = basic("un", "pw"); 
given() 
.relaxedHTTPSValidation() 
.cookie("SMCHALLENGE","YES") 
.baseUri("dit.MyCompany.com") 
// .param ("p1", "1234") 
// .param ("p2", "XYZ") 
.when() 
.get("/packages/stats") 
.then() 
.assertThat().statusCode(200); 
}`
@RichardSand

Comment: Its hard to troubleshoot further without knowing exactly what response you are getting back and why it works in your browser but not the code. If you can simulate the same request in your browser and use a tracing tool like Fiddler2 then you should be able to see exactly how it goes through